# Get number of Array stored in variable

Tags: php, arrays

I am storing those values coming from arrays in a SQL database successfully, but I would like to store the number inside `[0]=>`, in this case, `0` (or `2` from `[2]=>`) also in that SQL row.

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["tp"]=>
    string(1) "g"
    ["h"]=>
    string(1) "a"
    ["t"]=>
    string(2) "18"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["tp"]=>
    string(1) "g"
    ["h"]=>
    string(1) "a"
    ["t"]=>
    string(1) "8"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["tp"]=>
    string(1) "c"
    ["h"]=>
    string(1) "h"
    ["t"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the keys that exist in the array? `array_keys()`?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Comment: So ou want us to write the code for you... ??? At least show us what you have tried...

Comment: The code you've already got is presumably looping over this array - just include the key in the loop.

Comment: I get the key values successfully, but I want the number of the subarray `0` for  `[0]=>` or `1`for `[1]=>` in a variable as well. No idea how to do that. Sorry even no idea how to try.

Comment: If you get the keys successfully, how come you can't use that? The key is `0` for the first subarray, `1` for the second and so on. `array_keys()` will give you all of them, and you can use that in a loop to put them into variables if you need.

Comment: Guess I have problems to express my needs. I have solved it using http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php now. Thanks for your time guys!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you want to achieve, maybe something like this can help?

```
foreach ($your_array as $k => $v) {
    $your_array[$k]['key'] = $k;
}
```